# Ortelius and Nicolosi projection in QGIS

Tags: qgis, proj

I am trying to define ortelius oval projection and Nicolosi globular projection in QGIS using proj4 foramt as described in documentation but QGIS is unable to project into these projection even if they are supported in proj4 library... I need those projection for further analysis of old maps.

Does anybody know what could be the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are out of luck with your attempt, because there is no inverse projection defined in PROJ.4 for the two projections you want.

QGIS depends on GDAL, and for any kind of reprojection the inverse projection has to be defined to be able to show projected data in the GUI or use command line tools.

That is the reason why GDAL (and QGIS) supports less than half of the projections defined in PROJ.4.

Comment: I try to do the same in SAGA GIS that used PROJ.4 library as well and is capable to project the shapefile into desired projection (nicolosi and ortelius) but it isi not capable to project these projections into any other with an error "Inverse transformation not available"... So now I can be sure that this is impossible to do. Thanks for your answer!